# Generate content in a log file between two commits in Git

Tags: git

I want to generate the content of all files committed in Git between to commits in a single log file. I have to skip binary files content during this process. Only include java, SQL, JSP, js files. This is for the code scan for standards and security checks.

I tried the following command which is including all files.

```
git diff 84fe469e1d7..b4ffd226cc8 --oneline > difflog.txt
```

Could anyone suggest if there is a way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? You can add other patterns for other extensions too.

```sh
git diff 84fe469e1d7..b4ffd226cc8 --oneline -- *.java > difflog.txt
```

Comment: What is **--oneline** in `git diff --oneline`?!

Comment: It don't know, I've just kept it from the OP. But it does not error, so it must be doing something, I guess...

Comment: @phd, I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045040/what-does-oneline-in-git-diff) about it.