# What does --oneline in git diff do?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040710/5825294) answer of mine, I have kept from the question an option I didn't know of, namely `--oneline` applied to `git diff` instead of `git log`. But searching for `oneline` in `man git-diff` doesn't give any result. Still `git diff --oneline` doesn't error.

What is it for?

Comment: I would guess it's shorthand for `--pretty=oneline`

Comment: @CodeCaster, but not even that is in `man git-diff`, so the question stays the same, I guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's `git diff`, not `git log`!

Comment: @phd I'm saying that an option explicitly documented for `git log` but not for `git diff` does not error with the latter, so what does it do?

Comment: I think it does nothing. I believe it's ignored. I suspect there's a common code in `git` to parse command line options and it allows options that are used for different subcommands; but that requires further investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) documentation, the command shows the changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc. The [git-diff-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) command is part of git-diff, it compares two tree objects. This makes it possible to use the option. It is a short form of `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`. I also found a comment in the [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation:

> The command takes options applicable to the git rev-list command to control what is shown and how, and options applicable to the git diff-* commands to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.

So I suspect it is a possible option for a subcommand, but it has no effect on the git-diff command.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff --oneline` does nothing special. It just so happens that `git log` and `git diff` share a large part of the command line parser (because all the `diff` options also apply to `log`). For this reason, `git diff` does not complain about the presence of `--oneline` and only ignores it.